# How to tell SQLexec not to wrap characters?

Tags: oracle11g, line, word-wrap, spool

I'm using Oracle 11g. Also using the spool command to get the output of a query to a file. The problem is that sqlexec is wrapping the characters and making my life miserable. Now under normal circumstances this might be fine however the spool file is on average a 100,000 lines and more so because sqlexec keeps giving me line breaks .... which I don't want. Is there a way to tell sqlexec and/or the spool command to have no line wraps?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer for anyone coming upon this ... Within the spool file or at the command prompt for sqlplus type this

```
set linesize 256;
```

where 256 is the number of characters you want it to display. In my case I'm dealing with 256 varchar's.